# How to build a dataset with h5py?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, h5py

I have the following dataset :

class category : 1,2,3 each class contain rgb images 320x240

```
dataset
   |---- training_set
         |---- 1
               |--- rgb_1.png
               |--- rgb_2.png
         |---- 2
               |--- rgb_1.png
               |--- rgb_2.png
         |---- 3
               |--- rgb_1.png
               |--- rgb_2.png
   |---- test_set
         |---- 1
               |--- rgb_1.png
               |--- rgb_2.png 
         |---- 2
               |--- rgb_1.png
               |--- rgb_2.png
         |---- 3
               |--- rgb_1.png
               |--- rgb_2.png
```

Because when I training the model In google colab it is very slow than my computer, I think because the dataset is in google drive, so I try another solution to create the dataset using h5py.

Please, How to build this dataset with h5py ?

Comment: Can you please show the code you've tried? We can help you work through the errors you are running into. You can also look at h5py's documentation https://h5py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/high/dataset.html

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is use `create_dataset()`. Everything you need is in the link provided by @jakub. To populate the dataset, you need to create a NumPy array from your image. I don't know the best way to do that. You will need to figure that part out. For my example, I used `cv2.imread()`.

You can get started with this simple piece of code:

```
import h5py, cv2
import numpy as np
# Create an array for image data
img_arr = cv2.imread(imgFile)
# returns a np array 
with h5py.File('imagedata.h5','w') as h5f :
    dset = h5f.create_dataset("image1", data=img_arr)
```